# Posting data without refresh + calling another jquery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

My code, basically, on a click of a button, runs an ajax function in order to write stuff to my database.

What I want to do next is call another function which will fetch data from the database and print it.

Here is my code below, but the second function does not show that it works. I don't know where I went wrong.

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    function loaddata() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/fetchupdatedimages.php",
            data: $("#editad_form").serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

Second function:

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#deleteimgs").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/deleteimages.php",
                data: $("#editad_form").serialize()
            });

            $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent().remove();
            loaddata();
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

fetchupdatedimages.php

```php
<?php
    include_once "functions.php";

    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(-1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $id = $_POST["id"];
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT images FROM db WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($images);
        $stmt->fetch();
    }

    echo "<p>" . $images . "</p>";
 ?>
```

It seems that `loaddata()` does not get called or it does not return any data to me back. Any help?

Comment: see console for errors, set some alert message in loaddata() and go to network tab and see your browser makes a connection to deleteimages.php and connection is 200 ok and also goto response tab and see if you have got any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried sending the data from your `PHP` file using `JSON` over to your `jQuery` code instead?

For example:

### PHP

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    include 'connect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM reviews, customers WHERE review_user = customer_id";
    $datas = "";
    $x = 0;
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $datas[$x] = array("fname" => $row["customer_name"], "lname" => $row["customer_surname"], "email" => $row["customer_email"], "gender" => $row["customer_gender"], "title" => $row["review_title"], "content" => $row["review_content"], "rating" => $row["review_rating"]);
            $x++;
        }
    }
    $con->close();
    echo json_encode($datas);
?>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('controls/getReviews.php', function(jsondata) {
        console.log("Returned data: " + jsondata);
        if (jsondata !== "") {
            for (var i = 0; i < jsondata.length; i++) {
                var data = jsondata[i];
                var fname = data["fname"];
                var lname = data["lname"];
                var email = data["email"];
                var gender = data["gender"];
                var title = data["title"];
                var msg = data["content"];
                var rating = data["rating"];
                $('.reviews').append('<div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">' + title + '</h3></div><div class="panel-body"><table class="table table-striped"><tr><td>Name:</td><td>' + fname + ' ' + lname + '</td></tr><tr><td>Gender:</td><td>' + gender + '</td></tr><tr><td>Rating:</td><td>' + rating + '/5</td></tr><tr><td>Message:</td><td>' + msg + '</td></tr></table></div></div>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```